# rawQuery not comparing integer value

Tags: android, sqlite

I want my rawQuery to populate my data according to these 2 conditions. But it is showing and empty listview. It is not comparing the second condition.

```
Cursor c = db.myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT _id, word,definition,sentence,yourstory,isfavor FROM words WHERE word LIKE ? AND isfavor= ? ",new String[]{""+employeeId+"%",""+'1'});
```

Comment: Not relevant to question, but you could change your string[] to `{employeeId+"%","1"}`

Comment: `'1'` or `"1"` are strings, so if the values in the isfavor column are numbers, this would indeed be the problem.